# How can I exclude external dependencies from debug symbols?

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, pdb-files

I am trying to compile a debug version of C++ code in Visual Studio 2017 and I am getting a compiler error:
C1067   compiler limit : debug information module size exceeded

This is due to a class in a file which is in external dependencies having too many members. I don't care about having debug symbols for any of the external dependencies, so is there a way to exclude them from being included in debug symbols?

Comment: What about setting *Debug Information Format* to *None* for the file(s) containing class implementation?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot (or don't know how to) set Debug Information Format for individual files. There is nothing like that in file properties and Debug Information Format is set (for all files at once) in the makefile.

Comment: You can right click **on the *.cpp* file, not the project**, and select *Properties*. If you're doing things from a *Makefile*, you could create a rule for that particular file.

Comment: Changing the makefile to accomplish this seems complicated to me. Splitting the class in two solved my immediate problem, although your comment actually gives the precise answer to the question I asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the control of the class, you can try [#pragma component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/component?view=vs-2017) like [this issue](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/c1067-compiler-limit.1429486/).

If you don't have the control of it. Then maybe you can try right-click project properties=>C/C++=>General=>Debug Information Format to none like CristiFati's suggestion.

Anyway, I think redesign the structure of the class could be better though it may take much time.

Comment: It seems that makefile is overriding these commands or maybe I made a mistake while trying to do that, but splitting the structure that was causing problems in two solved my problem. Thank you.